# How to direct include Vue.js <script> in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, cdn, vuejs

I want to use Vue.js in Magento 2 by the **[Direct  Include](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Direct-lt-script-gt-Include)** , but, for some reason, the script doesn't call the content and then, the local Vue script doesn't work.

[image: ReferenceError: Vue is not defined]

I put the CDN in the header with the others
[image: Scripts and stylesheets in Content > Configuration > Edit Theme > HTML Head]

And is here in the page "loaded"
[image: Ricght click in the page > Code font page]

The HTML and Vue content works in codepen and others platforms

```js
var gobantesCatalogos = new Vue({
  el: '#catalogs',
  data: {
    urlComun: '/pub/media/wysiwyg/catalogo/',
    items: [
      { titulo: 'File1', nombreArchivo: 'FileName1', nombreImagen: 'img1' },
      { titulo: 'File2', nombreArchivo: 'FileName2', nombreImagen: 'img2' },
      { titulo: 'File3', nombreArchivo: 'FileName3', nombreImagen: 'img3' },
      { titulo: 'File4', nombreArchivo: 'FileName4', nombreImagen: 'img4' },
      { titulo: 'File5', nombreArchivo: 'FileName5', nombreImagen: 'img5' },
      { titulo: 'File6', nombreArchivo: 'FileName6', nombreImagen: 'img6' }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<h1>Catalogue</h1>
<div id="catalogs" class="columnss">
    <div class="column-lg-3 column-md-4 column-xs-6" v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <a v-bind:href="urlComun + item.nombreArchivo" class="catalogue" target="_blank" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + urlComun + item.nombreImagen + ')' }">
            <div class="fondo">
                <h2 class="titulo">{{ item.titulo }}</h2>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

But, doesn't work in the page. Anyone has tried to use Vue.js in Magento 2 without PWA Vue Storefront?
What did I miss?

Thanks you for read it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In magento you should avoid inject direct script in templates like

```
<script defer="" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Not like that

The correct way below

You can add path vue js to file requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    paths: {
       vue: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue',
       vuelocal: '<ModuleName>/js/vue',
       vueFallbacksDependency: [
         "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue",
         "secondFallbackSourceVueIncaseFirstOneFailLoad"
       ]
    }

    
}; 
/*No js extension after vue*/
```

Inside your template just call (you also can put js code below to seperate file instead include in phtml)

```
<script>
  require(["vue", "domReady!"], function (Vue) {
    return function (config, element) {
      var vueInstance = new Vue({el: element, data: {config}});
      return vueInstance;
    }
  });
</script>
```

You can add file requirejs-config.js inside you current theme default or luma (magento default)

the path will be

> app/design/frontend/YourVendor/Yourtheme/requirejs-config.js

Last step in template file (phtml) here is markup code for render vue data

```
<div class="vue-init" data-mage-init='{"vue":{}}'>
   <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh and why we should avoid that? There is security or performance reasons? Thanks you so much for the answer, I'm going to try this way and I tell you what happens.

Comment: because js combine mechanism in magento use requirejs way. Js resource path  define in requirejs-config

Comment: because your vue file put to head tag of html so when template parse and recall new Vue! At this moment vue js file still not load yet
Requirejs make sure load js after all html paint and render success

Comment: I understand now, thanks you very much, now works :))))